# No UI dialogs in MS Azure / SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, ssms

Recently, I purchased a licence for a Microsoft Azure SQL Server 2012 (packet "S0" - Standard, 250 GB)

When I connect with SQL Server Management Studio 2012 to this database, then all the user interface dialogs for creating tables, setting up users, etc. are gone.

You can only script and execute pure SQL statements.

Even the table editor is gone, so you even cannot edit the data in a table!

If I connect to a local database, then everything works. So the problem must be related to the Azure Database. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is Azure SQL Database, then keep in mind that this is not the same as SQL Server 2012 although you can use the same tools to connect to it.  This behavior is therefore correct and normal.  If you have installed or used an image for SQL Server on a VM then you should have everything as you expect.

Comment: "This behaviour is correct" ? To me, this is a crippled product then.  I clearly purchased a "SQL Server 2012" license, hosted on MS Azure. And technically, I can't understand this behaviour, because eventually, the SSMS creates SQL statements in background, so why does this not work.

Comment: BTW, in the connection, it says "SQL Server 11.0.9226"

Comment: When you see your sql server/database in azure portal where is it?  Your license is full blown sql server which should therefore run as an image in a vm.  The behaviour you describe is correct of the other version but not that.  Did you provision a VM image?

Comment: I'm afraid you are right. I got it confirmed by Microsoft itself. BTW, a lot of people are complaining about this, it has 524 user votes already in azure feedback. http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/476408-full-management-studio-support

Comment: Hopefully, they bring it in line in time.  It does drive me nuts as well as everyone else.  Sorry for being right :-)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-2014-management-studio-updated-support-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx