# SQL Server Management Studio Logins Dialog missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms, login-script

I am running SQL Server Management Studio v17.6.

The online tutorials for creating a new Login show a dialog that comes up when your right-click on Logins and select New Login.

I don't see this dialog; instead I get a script to `CREATE LOGIN` which is OK but I would prefer the dialog.

I don't see an option to switch from getting a script to getting the dialog.  I don't know if this version does not have the dialog or if I am just not finding the option.

[image]

Comment: Are you selecting "New Login..." or "Script Login As>Create To>New Query Editor Window"?

Comment: I am selecting "New Login."  This seems to be true for other actions such as adding a new user.  I just get the script.

Comment: Do you have any addons in SSMS?

Comment: No addons.  Does using Azure make a difference?

Comment: I have not used Azure in a few years, but I wouldn't doubt if that is a limitation.

Comment: That seems to be it.  Thanks for responding.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978549/no-ui-dialogs-in-ms-azure-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 15):

Currently this is an Azure SQL limitation.

More information can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/adding-users-to-your-sql-azure-database/) on azure.microsoft.com or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins) on Microsoft docs.

When creating a new login with the following SSMS menu item:

[image]

this is what appears with an Azure SQL database:

[image]

instead a dialog window appears when using a local database:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also found a helpful post that explains the limitations at the time of this post.

[Azure SQL limitations](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/azure-sql-limitations-compared-with-a-sql-server-enterprise-1)

What I did was inside SSMS, while connected to your Azure SQL instance, make sure you are first connected to the master database as shown:

[image]

Then run this script with your values against the master DB.

CREATE LOGIN WorldCitiesLogin
WITH PASSWORD = N'<your_password>'
GO

Next, switch your instance in SSMS to the database you want to map your login:

[image]

Then, run this script with your user name that maps to the newly created login above:

CREATE USER WorldCitiesUser
FOR LOGIN WorldCitiesLogin
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo]
GO