# new user/login GUI missing in SSMS 2017

Tags: ssms, ssms-2017

I'm new to azure and I've created a new SQL DB and I want to create a read-only user for my DB (so I can use it in my web app) but when I go to create a new login/user (right click security folder >  select new login/user) I get a query tab instead of the GUI that I see in all the examples for creating a user. Did MS do away with the new user/login GUI or are there some settings that are not on that control whether or not that GUI screen shows?

Comment: Currently this is a SQL Azure limitation see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52094766/909742).

Comment: wow, that sucks. Thanks for the info