# Creating new user in SSMS with dialog box

Tags: sql-server-2017, ssms-2017

When I create a user in SSMS (Security, New, Login) it no longer presents a dialog box to me.  It now creates Transact SQL code in a query window.  Did I change a setting somewhere? Sorry for asking, but I've done all the Google searches I can think of and haven't been able to figure out what I did.  I'm on SSMS v17.9 with a SQLServer 2017 Azure database.

Comment: Currently this is an Azure SQL limitation. see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52094766/909742